# Xamarin Forms Custom Control using renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, renderer

I would like to create custom controls using xamarin android visual studio. I have created this as sample project using xamarin forms and it works fine: http://blog.falafel.com/learning-xamarin-custom-renderers-in-xamarin-forms/

Now my req is I want to create something like: [image]

Above control I have created using fragment - android native controls. I want to create now exactly same in Xamarin Forms using Renderer.

Answer (score 1):

The following [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/videos/cross-platform/xamarinforms-custom-renderers/) is a great tutorial to get you into how to write custom renderers, along with the code sample [here](http://bit.ly/xf-customrenderer).

If you follow the essence of there example you will see how to write an **Android** renderer and be able to test it, *however* for what you are trying to do you have to make some alterations.

You will want to specify the **assembly** **ExportRendererAttribute** to expose your custom renderer and allow this to be registered for use.  This will then make your class implementation callable when it is encountered rendering a **Xamarin.Forms** page.

As you are creating a composite control you will want to derive also from **ViewRenderer<>** passing your custom **View** that is shared across all platform implementations, and the *base* control that you will use for hosting your new composite control (look at your sample composition that you already have done and take the top-most element).

Unlike the example in the link you will not override the **Draw** method as you are not going to be painting directly onto the **Canvas**.  Instead you will create your layout following what you have already done, but you will place this code within the override **OnElementChanged()**.